# Xamarin Forms - Label, Color and other attribute doesn't update when their Binded attributes are set

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, xamarin.forms, updates

I'm comming because I don't understand something about the binding..

I have this attribute in the C# code:

```
public string MyText { get; set; }
```

and then in the XAML part:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

The first time it works, but if I change `MyText` string, then the `<Label/>` doesn't update..

I also saw some post about it, where people speak about `INotifyChange` or something like that, how does work this Bind? Why the update isn't constant and why it just not work same always?

The problem is that my projet is a bit complex. I have a **customCalendar** I made by myself which is a **Grid** "bind by myself again" to a `DayCase[6][7]` such as *Windows calendar*, the display is the same.

So my question is double, does I need 1 function by attribute to "*listen*" if one of them change? Because in the example, I just speak about one Label, but I have 1 label by DayCase, 3 Color to update, a title with Month/Year to update, etc etc

I really lost honestly, I'm sure to know how to think, how to make it..

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make binding work. Your ViewModel needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it has an handler `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged`, which Xamarin.Forms' binding system to hook up with, and create an invoker for it:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var eventHandler = PropertyChanged;
            eventHandler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
```

After that, write your property that to be bind like this:

```
private string _myText;
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return _myText; }
        set
        {
            if (_myText != value)
            {
                _myText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyText)));
            }
        }
    }
```

For details, please read https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Also, there are other MVVM frameworks (MvvmCross, Mvvm Light, etc.) or Xamarin.Forms.Lab already did some work for you.

For your **customCalendar** issue, since to let binding work is to invoke PropertyChanged event, you can write a method to handle this like

```
public void UpdateDayCase(int i, int j, DayCase)
{
    this.DayCases[i][j] = DayCase;
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DayCases)));
}
```

Comment: Wow, your answer is just perfect ! Everything is working and sorry, I didn't saw your edit, which is interesting, but I already made something by my own :) Thank anyway for it ;) However, it's a bit boring this duplicating but it works, that's the main goal ;)